# Nutch + Solr; SolrDeleteDuplicates deletes all but one index

Tags: solr, rss, indexing, duplicates, nutch

I've got a server running Nutch, which feeds to Solr. Nutch's input is an rss feed's xml, and it seems to be using the proper feed plugin to parse it.

When running a basic crawl, it crawls and identifies the various links in the xml properly, and indexes the correct number of documents. However, SolrDeleteDuplicates seems to delete all but one - the one that doesn't get deleted seems to be random.

```
 Indexing 21 documents
 SolrIndexer: finished at 2013-11-15 13:53:53, elapsed: 00:00:22
 SolrDeleteDuplicates: starting at 2013-11-15 13:35:53
 SolrDeleteDuplicates: Solr url: http://localhost:8983/solr
 SolrDeleteDuplicates: deleting 20 duplicates
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have mis-configured your deduplication setup to look at the field that is identical for all entries. So, Solr thinks they are all the same records.

If this does not, update your question with the configuration you have for the dedupe component.